# Karabiner on Mac: how to map right_option to right_control only if previous pressed key is not right_command?

Tags: macos, remapping, button-remapping

I'm currently mapping my `right_option` key to `right_control` but there are some times where I would like to run the `right_command + right_option + other key` combination and would love to do it with the same `right_option` key. Is there a way to make the `right_option` key to act normally only when the previous pressed key has been `right_command` and/or is used for this specific combinations? I could also just try to map `right_control + right_command` to `right_option + right_command` but I'm not even sure how to do that with Karabiner.

Or is there any other easier alternative?